# Viewpager set current item async

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have View pager with 1000 items placed in fragment. When fragment is create i need to move viewPager to 600th item. below is code how i actually do that, but it takes some time.

```
mPager.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(600, false);
    }
});
```

Is it some way to make it async/smoother ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you cannot touch UI elements from background thread so what you can do to speed it up is to load more item at once like setting the `ViewPager.offScreenPageLimit()`.

For example I am setting 100 but you can set more and test it then:

```
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(100);
```

Also use true in `setCurrentItem()` to make it smoother. Like:

```
mPager.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(600, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you but i tried set bigger OffscreenPageLimit but it is much slower than before. Also set boolean value to true dont help very well because there are 600 items add it just jump to 600th item.

Comment: Nice method "post" for ViewPager, very interesting... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arslan answer is good.
Also, if you are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, be aware of issues mentioned here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=37990.
These happens especially when you have offScreenPageLimit() mentioned less than (NO_OF_ITEMS - 1). These issues occur when user swipes as the StatePagerAdapter deletes the fragment when it is no more required and creates it back when it is required.The indexing is not taken properly in this adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but i don't change items order and also i don't detect any issues.